# Conditioning a Poisson process on the number of arrivals in a fixed time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let T1 and T5 be the first and fifth arrivals in a Poisson process with rate lambda.

(a) Find the conditional density of T1 given that there are 10 arrivals in the time interval (0,1)

(b) Find the conditional density of T5 given that there are 10 arrivals in the time interval (0,1)

I feel like this question should be really easy but i'm not sure where to get started.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose $T_n = x$.  how many arrivals were there in $(0,x)$ and how many were there in $(x,10)$? What's the probability that this happened?

Comment: Note that since you know how many arrivals there were in the interval, the rate $\lambda$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not understanding how Tn=x helps out with this. I feel like that's not solving for the density of T1 or T5 specifically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N_1$ denote the number of events in $(0,1)$. For every $n\geqslant1$, conditionally on $[N_1=n]$, the random set $\{T_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$ is distributed like $\{U_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$ where $(U_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is an i.i.d. sample from the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. This implies for example, that the event $[T_1\geqslant t]$ has the same probability as the event $[U_1\geqslant t,U_2\geqslant t,\ldots,U_n\geqslant t]$, namely, $(1-t)^n$. Thus, conditionally on $[N_1=10]$,
$$
f_{T_1}(t)=10\,(1-t)^9\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1}.
$$
You might want to adapt this argument to the case of $T_5$ conditionally on $[N_1=10]$.

Comment: @Any idea how to solve this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253101/conditional-inter-arrival-times-for-poisson-and-renewal-process

Comment: @Su20200 I see no clear question there, at present.

Comment: @Did Is there a textbook, wikipedia link, etc that I can use to cite this fact? (i.e. the independence of U_1,...,U_n ) Thanks!

Comment: @afshi7n Any book on the Poisson process would do, which one are you using? Note that the first hits of a search engine, all explaining this, are  [1](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~yibi/teaching/stat317/2014/Lectures/Lecture10_6up.pdf) [2](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-PP-NSPP.pdf) [3](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Stochastik/lehre/WS1314/BachelorWT/Daten/StPro_Ross1.pdf).

Comment: Great, it seems like Ross's Stochastic Processes book will do (your third reference). Thanks a lot!